# Why both userPassword and krbPrincipalKey

Tags: ldap, openldap, kerberos, freeipa, mitkerberos

When configuring MIT Kerberos to use an LDAP database instead of DB2, I was surprised to see that user password hashes are stored in two different fields: userPassword and krbPrincipalKey.  Seems the hashing algorithms may be different, but that seems unnecessary too.  Why not just consolidate to avoid synchronization issues?

Answer (score 0):

OpenLDAP cannot directly handle `krbPrincipalKey` data for authentication. I am not entirely familiar with how FreeIPA handles handles passwords, but for other OpenLDAP/Kerberos installations, OpenLDAP is often instructed to use [SASL passthrough authentication](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html#Pass-Through%20authentication).

Comment: Yes, but why?  It seems it would be easier to update either Kerberos or the LDAP server to be able handle a different password field format then go through all the trouble to handle keeping two separate fields in sync or setting up an external SASL daemon for SASL passthrough.